# Server Exception : Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. \“File\r\n\”

Tags: sharepoint-server

So I have a ABC`(example.com/ABC)` folder in my server so if I edit some file which is inside that ABC folder it'll edit without any exceptions. I have another folder inside that ABC folder (`example.com/ABC/XYZ`). So if I edit the file which is inside my XYZ folder it is throwing this exception after `ExecuteQuery();`

```
item.File.Publish(publishComment);
SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

.

```
 public static bool EditPage(SPClient.ListItem item, string pageTitle, string pageContent, string publishComment)
        {
            var pageEdited = false;
            try
            {
                item["Title"] = pageTitle;
                item["PublishingPageContent"] = pageContent;
                item.Update();
                SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                item.File.Publish(publishComment);
                SharePointTools.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                pageEdited = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                pageEdited = false;
            }
            return pageEdited;
        }
```

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: looks like `item` is null. Make sure you are passing valid `item` object

Comment: item has the same value as ABC files item

Comment: I haven't found an answer to this. I have suddenly started getting this error randomly even though nothing is changing on the object from when it is working one day to the next. Did you have any luck fixing this permanently?